# DNN Modules Version

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am using the DotNetNuke 7 compiled module. I added DotNetNuke 6.25 as a reference. If I want to use this module for DNN 7, do I need to change the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically don't need to recompile a module for a newer version of DNN, unless of course you are using something that isn't supported in a newer release. For example, the DNN 7 services layer changed from what it was in Version 6.

The opposite isn't true however, you can't compile against DNN7 and have the module run against DNN6, unless of course you recompile.